# Find number of distinct values in a specific column in a Rails find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing a find in Rails model as follows:

```
@jobs = Job.find(:all, :conditions => ["job_id = ?", params[:id]])
```

The result of this query also brings back data from an associated model JobResponses (there are multiple JobResponses for each Job record).  Once I have the JobResponse results I am calculating a number of different averages/medians etc for each set of Job results.

One of the columns returned in the JobResponses is company_id - so therefore I might get back 10 job responses (4 from Company A, 2 from Company B, 2 from Company C and 1 each from Company D & E) - 5 distinct companies.

How can I calculate/display the number of distinct companies that returned a result for JobResponses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'm understand clearly, try following to get number of distinct companies:
@jobs.map(&:job_responses).flatten.map(&:company_id).uniq.size

Comment: This got me where I needed to go.  My final code was:

s.map(&:company_id).uniq.size

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, plain sql?

```
@jobs = Job.find_by_sql('select job.*, count(jr.id) as distinct_responses from job, job_responses jr where jr.job_id = job.id group by job.id')
```

each element of `@jobs` now have `distinct_responses` accessor